# How many unique lines from an integer coordinate to points on a rectangular lattice?

Tags: geometry

If I have a rectangular lattice (sorry if I'm not using that term correctly) as shown by the blue dots in the image below, and a point somewhere on integer coordinates (green dot in the image). How many unique lines are there from that point to points on the lattice that are shorter than a certain length? I'm using unique to mean none overlapping, so in the example below the distance is 4, so even though the point (4,0) is within range of the green dot, its on the same line as (1,0) so it wouldn't be counted. The red lines in the example are too long. Sorry if my terminology is off!

Also this is for a program, so an algorithm with a small big-O would be great as well!

EDIT 2: I'm asking for the generalization for a rectangular lattice with any width and height between the points, not just the case below which has a height of 2 and a width of 3

EDIT 3: I only need the number of paths not the paths themselves, but I do need the exact number. The source of the question is a billiards game where you have a table with certain dimensions and you have a cue ball and 8 ball you want to hit, how many different ways can you hit the pool ball where it will hit the 8 ball only being able to going a certain distance. I got the lattice by unfolding the table, the lattice I get from that is uneven so I was just asking a simpler version of the question since the actual lattice is the same as two rectangular lattices offset.
[image: Lines example]

Comment: Is $O(r^2)$ good enough ($r$ the maximal distance)?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Maybe!, biggest r is 10,000, so that wouldn't be insane, the best I've gotten down to so far is around O(r^3)

Comment: Do you need an exact answer, or would a (good?) bound do? Do you need just the number of paths, or do you need the paths themselves? If you [edit] the question to provide a little more context about the source of the question we may be better able to help.

Comment: It's reasonably easy to get a list of all lattice points within a distance $r$ of a point in $O(r^2)$, so I assume your difficulty is with your "no overlaps" condition?

Comment: @user3482749 Yes! my current method checks all points and then checks the points against a list of all points previously found to be valid, which results a slow check for large r's

Answer (score 1):

So I assume your green dot is at $(0,0)$ and your lattice points are all points of the form $(a+bi,c+dj)$ with $i,j\in \Bbb Z$ (for some given $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Z$), and the maximal distance is $r$.
For simplicity, assume $b,d>0$.

It is easy to enumerate all lattice points $(x,y)$ at distance $\le r$ in $O(r^2)$ time; in fact, letting $i$ run over $\lceil -\frac {a+r}b\rceil,\ldots, \lceil \frac {r-a}b\rceil$ and $j$ over $\lceil -\frac {c+r}d\rceil,\ldots, \lceil \frac {r-c}d\rceil$, followed by a comparing $x^2+y^2=(a+ib)^2+(c+id)^2$ with $r^2$ is already an oversimplified such enumeration. It is also not hard to speed this up by roughly a factor of $\frac\pi 4$.

Hence a quick check whether another lattice point is on the same line and closer would give us an $O(r^2)$ algorithm for the problem.

Given a lattice point $(x,y)=(a+kb,c+ld)\ne(0,0)$, we first find all points with integral coordinates (i.e., on the standard lattice) on its line: Let $D=\gcd(x,y)$. Then these integer points are all the integer multiples of $(u,v):=(\frac xD,\frac yD)$, or counting from  the other end, equivalently all points of the form $(x,y)-n(u,v)$.
Note that $n$ produces a lattice point iff $nu$ is a multiple of $b$ and $nv$ a multiple of $d$. Equivalently, $n$ must be a multiple of $\operatorname{lcm}(\frac b{\gcd(b,u)},\frac d{\gcd(d,v)})$.
We are but interested only in sthose $n$ where $(x,y)-n(u,v)$ does not reach or even go beyond $(0,0)$.
Clearly, testing the smallest such $n$, i.e., the lcm itself is sufficient.

In summary, for given $(x,y)$ we compute

- $D=\gcd(|x|,|y|)$
- $u=\frac{|x|}D$, $v=\frac{|y|}D$
- $n=\operatorname{lcm}\left(\frac b{\gcd(b,u)},\frac d{\gcd(d,v)}\right)$

and finally check: Is $nu\le |x|$ and $nv\le |y|$ and at least one of the inequalities is strict? If the answer is yes, then do not count our point $(x,y)$ (as its line is already counted for a closer point).

Answer (score 0):

The unique lines pass through points with coprime coordinates.

Hence, the natural density of lines in the first quadrant is asymptotically $6/\pi ^{2}$ [[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coprime_integers#Probability_of_coprimality)].

I don't know the precise formulation in terms of lengths, though.