# Visibility of points on a rectangular lattice under a certain distance from the origin

Tags: geometry, number-theory, integer-lattices

If I have points a rectangular lattice such that each point takes the form  of $(a+bi,c+dj)$ with $i,j\in \Bbb Z$ (for some given $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb Z$), and $b,d>0$. How can I find the number of visible points(Meaning that the line between the point and the origin contains no other points of the form previously mentioned) which are less than or equal to $r$ distance of the origin? I was looking through some articles on lattice visibility and couldn't find anything about rectangular lattices(Although I may just not have understood when they were discussing them) If anyone has a link to a paper which talks about this that would be great, or a solution would be amazing.

For context I'm trying to find the solution for this when there are 4 of these rectangular lattices overlaid on each other such that the points take the form $(\pm a+bi, \pm c+dj)$

EDIT: I'm writing an algorithm to solve this, and $O(N^2)$(ish) is either too slow, or there's a very weird edge case I'm not realizing

EDIT 2: here's an example where $r = 4$, so even though the point (4,0) is within range of the green dot, its on the same line as (1,0) so it wouldn't be counted. The red lines in the example are too long. [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LMxuB.png)

Comment: The title mentions *visibility*, but the only question in the body doesn't, it just asks for the number of points (visible or not) within a given distance of the origin. Please edit for consistency.

Comment: OK, you've edited the word *visibility* into the body of your post, that's good, but it's not clear what it means. There's a reference to "that same line", but since you haven't mentioned any line it's not clear what that could mean. Maybe you mean *not blocked by any other point from the point of view of an observer at the origin*. Anyway, I think a further edit is in order.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Should I just delete the question and try again?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you for being so helpful!

Comment: No need to delete, it's a good question now. But how does it differ from your earlier question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3876863/how-many-unique-lines-from-an-integer-coordinate-to-points-on-a-rectangular-latt ?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I wanted to rephrase it in terms of visibility since that a thing people do research on, and I also wanted to see if anyone knew of any papers on it, sorry if that's not a good way of going about things!

Comment: It's definitely not good to post the same question twice, and it's not good to post related questions without linking them to each other.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So should I delete this one and add some keywords to the other one so that people can find it easier if they are looking for similar problems? I found the answers I was looking for elsewhere so I don't need this post answered

Comment: If you have found the answers, let me encourage you to write them up and post them as an answer to (one of) your questions.